# How to define alias containing here-document

Tags: bash, unix, alias, heredoc

I have a command which I can execute as follows:

```
$ cmd<<EOF|gvim -
```

Attempted to alias the command as such, in my .alias file:

```
alias cmd='cmd<<EOF|gvim -'
```

When I source the alias file, I get:

```
$ . ./.alias
bash: ./.alias: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: ./.alias: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How can I define a correct alias? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a command, it's just a part of the command. The command ends where the here-doc ends.

Answer (score 0):

If your command line starts with `cmd<<EOF|gvim -`, that means you need to terminate the here document (which I assume you are entering manually) with `EOF`. Instead, just let `cmd` read from standard input, which you can terminate using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

That is, instead of

```
$ cmd<<EOF | gvim -
> your text
> goes here
> EOF
```

you use

```
$ cmd | gvim -
your text
goes here
^d
```

where `^d` is just <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

Then, you can define a function

```
mycmd () {
    cmd | gvim -
}
```

As a general rule, avoid defining aliases that do anything more than add options to a single command, e.g., `alias ls='ls --color'`.